# Replace List within Struct with another List

Tags: elixir

I have this struct:

```
%MyApp.ScoreTable{
  __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "score_tables">,
  id: "7f320636-2176-4af2-9207-6251416dd6c2",
  inserted_at: ~N[2018-11-04 21:08:26.024733],
  question: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :question is not loaded>,
  question_id: "dadc6e57-49f4-4339-9c0f-d40dbc6df534",
  season: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :season is not loaded>,
  season_id: "c356bae0-bee8-45df-b035-dc117908bebd",
  table_details: %MyApp.TableDetails{
    information: [
      %{
        "team_id" => "7ca4c7ac-850b-4f27-8b6e-1feeb1e0629b",
        "team_score" => "N/A"
      },
      %{"team_id" => "f78c069d-1500-4cfe-a201-13223c417f82", "team_score" => 5},
      %{"team_id" => "4b3459a0-f81c-436d-a68c-3a00dea62a2d", "team_score" => 5},
      %{"team_id" => "9dff5653-dee4-4fef-9d91-7d53f3861275", "team_score" => 10},
      %{"team_id" => "dab53fe6-419b-4a86-a1c6-9c1f65445e12", "team_score" => 15}
    ]
  },
  updated_at: ~N[2018-11-04 21:08:26.024739]
}
```

And I want to replace fully the `table_details.information` list with this one:

```
[
  %{
    "team_id" => "cebda2b5-26e1-4804-8529-17367155db06",
    "team_place" => 1,
    "team_score" => 5
  },
  %{
    "team_id" => "ea800d1c-a079-4f6f-9a91-2a085779dfa9",
    "team_place" => 1,
    "team_score" => 5
  },
  %{
    "team_id" => "2d9253fa-63b7-45dd-bf8f-370598a1424c",
    "team_place" => 3,
    "team_score" => 10
  },
  %{
    "team_id" => "1748f471-08ae-49ed-844b-0fe1bc539a8f",
    "team_place" => 4,
    "team_score" => 15
  },
  %{
    "team_id" => "df2f5102-4e6f-4480-8167-ebe0548cd4ba",
    "team_place" => 5,
    "team_score" => "N/A"
  }
]
```

To be clear, I want to wholesale swap the old list with the new list of maps. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the struct update syntax. Assuming your whole datastructure is stored in `data` and the new list in `new_information`, something like this will work:

```
data = %{data | table_details: %{data.table_details | information: new_information}}
```

Note that the update syntax creates a new version of the structure, so you need to assign it to a variable or return it from your function as appropriate.

Sometimes it's more clear what you're trying to achieve if you use [Access](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) with the associated [Kernel](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/2) macros. In this case:

```
data = put_in(data, [Access.key(:table_details), Access.key(:information)], new_information)
```

This basically does the same thing, but you only need to specify the path to the change and what to change. In the previous example one might make a mistake like `%{other_data.table_details | information: new_information}` (note `other_data` instead of `data`), in this case it's easy to see at a glance that only that one part of the structure is modified.

Comment: That is some awesome information. Thanks for the help.